# Multiple array in glob()

Tags: python, glob

I have the following code that works ok but slow when using the folder wildcard as the folders its parsing are many. I need to limit this to a list that i would like to provide it so as to limit its search;

How can I parse this folder list (such as folder=['A,B,C'] ) into glob so that it limits its search to these folders only  instead of using the * wildcard. This will make it work much faster due to the large number of folders.

```
tra=['70XX','81YY']
TargetFolder = r'C:\ELK\LOGS\ATH\DEST'
all_files = []
for directory in tra:
    files = glob.glob('Z:/{}/*/asts_data_logger/*.bz2'.format(directory))
    for f in files:
        current_path = Path(f)
        if current_path.name in filenames_i_want:
            print(f"found target file: {f}")
            shutil.copy2(f, TargetFolder)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through your list of folders and substitute them into the pathname, just like you did for the directories in `tra`.

```
import itertools

folders=['A', 'B', 'C']
tra=['70XX','81YY']
TargetFolder = r'C:\ELK\LOGS\ATH\DEST'
all_files = []
for directory, folder in itertools.product(tra, folders):
    files = glob.glob('Z:/{}/{}/asts_data_logger/*.bz2'.format(directory, folder))
    for f in files:
        current_path = Path(f)
        if current_path.name in filenames_i_want:
            print(f"found target file: {f}")
            shutil.copy2(f, TargetFolder)
```